# Display days labels on x-axis SSRS report builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I was following the instruction from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239316.aspx for setting up Date type interval and set it to Month and everything is showing up correctly, however if I narrow my interval to several days within month then chart again showing up correct data but don't label the days on x-axis. Is it possible to have days labels displayed having the month to be set as default interval?

Answer (score 0):

```
To format x-axis labels as daily intervals
1. Right-click the horizontal, or x-axis, of the chart, and select Horizontal Axis Properties.
2. In the Horizontal Axis Properties dialog box, select Number.
3. From the Category list, select Date. From the Type list, select a date format to apply to the x-axis labels. Select Axis Options.
4. In Interval, type 1. In Interval type property, select Days.
```

Note:
If you do not specify an interval type, the chart will calculate intervals in terms of days.
Click OK.

Comment: Your solution will work fine but when it comes to having interval of several months then the day labels are overlapping each other and graph becomes unreadable. Is the solution to deal with those limitations?

Comment: You have three options: 1) change day display on the axis label to be vertically displayed text instead of horizontal (this may save a little space) 2) don't display every single day 3) increase the overall size of the graph on the page.   The bottom line is that you have a finite amount of space within which to display data points, so the more data points and and axis labels you add, the more cluttered it is going to get.